# Magento 2: Layered navigation filter list issue

Tags: magento-2.1

Layered navigation filter returns empty result with below code. I want get active filter list

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$filterActive = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver');
$layerActive = $filterActive->get();
$activeFilters = $layerActive->getState()->getFilters();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to get active filters.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
)
{
    $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    $layer = $this->layerResolver->get();
    $activeFilters = $layer->getState()->getFilters();
}
```

Thanks. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I still have an empty array with the code above